# WordPress Mysql query with Category

Tags: wordpress

i've this query:

```
$querystr = "
SELECT  DISTINCT meta_value  FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN(     
SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta.post_id
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Country' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = 'UK' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ) AND meta_key ='city'
 ";
 $cities = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

<?php if ($cities ): ?>

 <?php global $post; ?>
 <?php foreach ($cities as $c): ?>    
 <?php echo $c->meta_value; ?> <br />    
 <?php endforeach; ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

I need to add search for "category name" or "category id"...how can i do it ?

Thanks ;)

**_______________________________**--

Thanks for reply,I've made some test but not works....can you help me anyway ? :)

```
$term_id = "SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name='foods' ";
$post_id = 'SELECT object_id FROM wp_terms_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id="$term_id->term_id';     
SELECT  DISTINCT meta_value  FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN(     
SELECT DISTINCT wpostmeta.post_id
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
AND wpostmeta.meta_key  = 'Country' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_value  = 'UK' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ) AND meta_key ='city'
AND wp_posts.ID = '$post_id->object_id'
```

Comment: Can you be bit more clear. Where is your category. ?

Comment: I need to add a search for category "foods" (ID: 56). How can i do it ?

Comment: Why don't you use pre defined functions for this? @CaponiElia

Answer (score 0):

You took it wrong that was just a explaination not the exact syntax , you need to it this way.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name='foods'", OBJECT );
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT object_id FROM wp_terms_relationships 
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id='$result->term_id'", OBJECT );
```

Now, you can pass this into your query this way.

```
 AND wp_posts.ID = '$post_id->object_id'
```

Comment: I've made some test but not works...can you help me with the query ?? Thanks !

Comment: I've added it on first post ;)

Comment: If i add $term_id and $post_id the query dont get results.

Comment: if you have multiple posts under this category , which is probably yes, then you need to iterate through a loop and then pass the value `$post_id->object_id` .